# How to test two django forms that are in the same view

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms

So I have a view that handles two different forms in the same POST request.

Previously the testing was easy because i had only one form so it would be something like:

```
def test_post_success(self):
    response = self.client.post("/books/add/", data={"title": "Dombey and Son"})

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.FOUND)
    self.assertEqual(response["Location"], "/books/")
```

If i have a **second form** with a 'prefix' how would i construct the **data** object of the request.

Im thinking of:

```
form_1_data = {foo}
form_2_data = {bar}
response = self.client.post("/books/add/", data={form_1_data, form_2_data)
```

But it clearly does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can combine dictionaries with `**` mark. Like this:

```
>>> data_1 = {"title": "Dombey and Son"}
>>> data_2 = {"character": "Donald Duck"}
>>> {**data_2, **data_1}
{'character': 'Donald Duck', 'title': 'Dombey and Son'}
```